# Schengen visa insurance duration

Tags: visas, schengen, insurance

I am applying for a tourist Schengen visa type C. It is unclear if they will grant me a multiple entry visa. My currently planned trip lasts for 30 days. So what should be the duration of the insurance?

The reason why I am asking is, is the number of entries dependent upon the duration of the insurance? That is, if the insurance is valid for 30 days then does that have any effect on issuing a multiple-entry visa (considering my first trip is 30 days)?

In other words, is having a 180 days insurance necessary for getting a multiple entry visa?

Answer (score 3):

I found a [related question with an answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42895/schengen-travel-insurance-for-3-entries?rq=1).

In short, the insurance has to be valid for the first trip.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer. The correct process on here is to close your question as a duplicate of the one you found, which I have already initiated. +1

Comment: +1, that will lift your rep to comment everywhere, hereafter please use comments to indicate duplicates so the others can close them appropriately.