# Do I buy travel Insurance for the length of my visit or the length of the visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, insurance

I'm going for a conference which would last 4 days. Should I buy travel insurance for the whole 3 months of my Schengen visa or just the length of my stay (4 days)?

Comment: You only need cover for the period when you are at risk so can you explain why you want to buy for a much longer period? Best to edit this into the question.

Comment: It's a good idea to compare costs. If you make several short trips a year, it might be cheaper in the longer term to buy an annual policy. Also, some bank accounts package travel insurance as one of their perks, perhaps yours does so worth a quick check. If you are travelling on business, does your employer offer any travel insurance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen travel insurance for 3 entries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42895/schengen-travel-insurance-for-3-entries)

Answer (score 4):

You buy insurance for the duration of the trip.

You do not need travel insurance for a time when you have a valid visa but are in your home country.

If you are delayed a day or so the insurance is normally extended to cover it, though you should make sure that is the case, or maybe buy insurance that covers five or six days. If your return is delayed for medical reasons your medical insurance should cover that.

Answer (score -1):

If you buy insurance for only four days, what happens if your return flight is delayed and you slip and break your leg in the airport a few hours into day five?

You need travel **and** medical insurance for the full duration of your trip including any unexpected delays.

Comment: People usually buy insurance till they return home. If your trip needs to be lengthened due to an accident or illness, a failure of airlines or some such, which is covered by the insurance, the cover will be lengthened by the insurance company.